# Set two values for span jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to put two values or data into my span. I am putting value into span like this:

`$('#spanid').text(data[i].phonenumber);`

the code above will put the phone number to the span now I want to make it in a way that if the data has another number like mobile number i will add it to the text if available. I put it like this:

`$('#spanid').text(data[i].phonenumber|| data[i].mobilenumber);`

But only the first value is set even if there is a value for mobile number.

Any idea is appreciated

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this

```
$('#spanid').text((data[i].phonenumber ? data[i].phonenumber +" , " :"") + " " +(data[i].mobilenumber? data[i].mobilenumber :"" ))
```

and you can also shorthand the second condition

```
$('#spanid').text((data[i].phonenumber ? data[i].phonenumber +" , " : "") + " " +(data[i].mobilenumber || "" ))
```

Comment: i am not sure but what i want is if only 1 number is available that number will appear if both are available both will appear.

Comment: i think this is what i mean.. is there a way to make it add `,` if two values are set?or i need to add condition for that like and `if statement`?

Comment: No, you don't need to add  the condition. Just update the `'||'` to comma `,`. See the updated post

Answer (score 0):

`||` condition for both object will return only first object if it has value to it. If you wish to use it as separator, you need to concatenate it in both data and then set it to span:

```
$('#spanid').text(data[i].phonenumber +"||"+ data[i].mobilenumber);
```

Comment: Will it not append || in text also

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a the `+` operator in the `text();` function to concatenate the strings:

```
$('#spanid').text(data[i].phonenumber + data[i].mobilenumber);
```

---

For putting both of the values within the `text()` function, with checking if they exist, i'd do something like this:

```
$('#spanid').text((data[i].phonenumber == "" ? "" : data[i].phonenumber) + (data[i].mobilenumber == "" ? "" : data[i].mobilenumber));
```

Comment: the `||` is an operator, not intended to be part of string

Comment: @charlietfl I used it for seperating the strings, for better readability. Btw, why is post downvoted?

Comment: Ah... Silent downvoters... For me, the main SO flaw. Big one.

Comment: @JeremyThille What do you mean?

Comment: @charlietfl Removed it btw, wasn't in the question.

Comment: I mean silent downvoters are a plague. I hate them. They just downvote your question or your answer, then go away. You don't have a clue why you have been downvoted and how you could improve. Just eat that. I wish StackOverflow forced downvoters to explain _why_ they downvoted, but it looks like they don't care.

Answer (score 0):

With your code the mobile number would only be displayed if there is no phone number. Try it with

```
$('#spanid').text((data[i].phonenumber || '') + (data[i].phonenumber && data[i].mobilenumber ? ", " : "") + (data[i].mobilenumber || ''));
```

Comment: yes what i want to happened is when both are available both of them will show if any of them is available that will be the one shown.

Comment: I changed my example to have the same behaviour for the phone number. The example should now work as you want it to.

Comment: Under Sachin's answer you want to have a comma seperator. Unfortunately his answer will output "[phone number]," even if there is no mobile number to follow. Updated my solution again to add the comma seperator.

Answer (score 0):

The further answers are MAYBE working, but concatinating strings like that is very slow, better don't do so.

Concatinating a strings is fastest like this:

```
[string1, string2].join('')
```

Comment: "is very slow"? Creating an array and calling a function is faster?

Comment: Where's the perf test that supports the `very slow` claim?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any operator like || to add in text. Just add-

```
$('#spanid').text(data[i].phonenumber +""+ data[i].mobilenumber);
```

So, if any one is present, it will be available in text. Or if both are present it will be in appended form

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/1oo4noed/

Answer (score 0):

In your `data object`

```
var data={
    phonenumber:222222222,
    mobilenumber:''
};
```

If `phonenumber` or `mobilenumber` is missing it should have `empty string`, `null` or `undefined` to identify value exist or not.
Assuming if `phonenumber` or `mobilenumber` is missing it will have `empty string`

```
var data={
    phonenumber:222222222,
    mobilenumber:''
};
var text = '';
if(data.phonenumber !='' && data.mobilenumber !='' ){
    text = data.phonenumber +','+ data.mobilenumber;
}
else if(data.phonenumber == ''){
    text = data.mobilenumber;
}
else{
    text = data.phonenumber;
}
$('#spanid').text(text);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wd0drwm4/)**